# Guidance needed for Invalid input error and collaborative class statistics for Grade Calculator

Tags: java

I am building a grade calculator in Java, I am having trouble adding a couple features to it, and it appears that I keep mucking it up too while I try to make changes. I have been working on it all week, and started over in the book and the powerpoint slides, and I just feel like there are just some pieces I am still not getting.

I need to make sure the invalid scores, reenter error shows up everytime a negative score is inputted. And then I need to calculate the class statistics of Average, Lowest and Highest scores. So basically a collaboration of how ever much data was inputted which could be any number of exams or students.

Here is my code, please let me know if you need more info. I am really new to this so I apologize that it is not the greatest.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class GradeCalculator {

public static void main(String[] args){

    double examAverage = 0, scoresEntered = 0, examSum = 0;  
    double totalExamSum = 0, allScoresEntered = 0;
    //variables for input

    Scanner GC = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner for integer inputs

    System.out.println("Welcome to Grade Calculator!" +"\n");

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of students:");
        int numberStudents = GC.nextInt();  
        //number of students input

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of exams:");
        int numberOfExams = GC.nextInt();
        //number of exams input

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberStudents; i++)  { 
            Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);                
            //scanner for student name input
            //Scanner for name input
            System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------");

            System.out.print("Enter student " + i + "'s name : " );
            String studentname = name.nextLine();
            //student name input

            System.out.print("Enter exam scores      : ");

        for (int j = 0; j < numberOfExams; j++) {
             scoresEntered = GC.nextDouble();
             examSum = (examSum + scoresEntered);}
             //score input and sum of all input scores
        do{
              System.out.println("Invalid exam scores, reenter: ");
              scoresEntered =GC.nextDouble();
       } while(scoresEntered<0);
        //my attempt at the Invalid exam score error

        examAverage = (examSum/numberOfExams);
        //examaverage calculator

        System.out.println("\n--------------------------------------");

             System.out.println("Grade Statistics for " + name);
             System.out.println("  Average   : " + examAverage);

    //Conditions and print outputs below for grade averages  
    if(examAverage <= 100 & examAverage >=90){
        System.out.println("  Letter Grade:  A");
        System.out.println("  " + name + " gets 4 stars! ****");
        examAverage = 0;
        examSum = 0;}

        else if(examAverage <=89.99 & examAverage >=80){
            System.out.println("  Letter Grade:  B");
            System.out.println("  " + name + " " + " gets 3 stars! ***");
            examAverage = 0;
            examSum = 0;}

        else if(examAverage <=79.99 & examAverage >=70){
            System.out.println("  Letter Grade:  C");
            System.out.println("  " + name + " " + " gets 2 stars! **");
            examAverage = 0;
            examSum = 0;}

        else if(examAverage <=69.99 & examAverage >=60){
            System.out.println("  Letter Grade:  D");
            System.out.println("  " + name + " " + " gets 1 stars! *");
            examAverage = 0;
            examSum = 0;}

        else if(examAverage <=59.99 & examAverage >=50){
            System.out.println("  Letter Grade:  F");
            System.out.println("  " + name + " " + " gets 0 stars!");
            examAverage = 0;
            examSum = 0;}

    //still need class statistics as well as help with the invalid exam scores, reenter error.
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What jumps out at me is the looping around your score input:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfExams; j++)
{
  scoresEntered = GC.nextDouble();
  examSum = (examSum + scoresEntered);
}

//score input and sum of all input scores
do
{
  System.out.println("Invalid exam score, reenter: ");
  scoresEntered = GC.nextDouble();
} while(scoresEntered < 0);
```

I've deliberately reformatted what you posted to try to make the problem more obvious.  What you appear to be doing is reading in all the scores.  Then, **regardless** of what was entered, you tell the user the exam scores are invalid and ask them to re-enter.  Remember, a do...while loop always executes at least once.  If the first re-entered score is above zero, that is all you'll read as the while condition is then satisfied.

If you are trying to validate each score before it is added to examSum, you need something more like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numberOfExams; j++)
{
  while ((scoresEntered = GC.nextDouble()) < 0)
    System.out.println("Invalid exam scores, reenter:  ");

  examSum = (examSum + scoresEntered);
}
```

Comment: Oh my gosh that helped A LOT. Thank you so much! It makes sense even when you read it aloud, wow. Like for this while it equals 0 print this. Thank you again!